# How can you test if a blogger site is online with an image?

Tags: html, blogger

When you want to test for an image to see if a site is available you normally go for the logo or an image that is likely to be present for a very long time.

When it comes to blogger, none of the images are hosted on your url but on one of bloggers static servers. This means you can't test the site for an image.

So how can you test to see if the site is online by loading an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one image hosted on your domain when it comes to blogger, and that's your favicon. You favicon is located at www.yourblogdomain.com/favicon.ico.

The common way to test for a status with an image is to try to load on online image and if it fails show the offline image.

To use the favicon you need to change the image when it is online and offline. to do this you use onerror and onload.

```
<img src="http://yousite.com/images/online.png" onerror="this.src='http://anothersite.com/offline.png'" />
```

For this to work the online image has to be hosted on the site you are checking. However if you want to check a blogger site or a site you don't have access to you need to do it another way.

```
<img src="http://test.blogspot.com/favicon.ico" onLoad="this.src='http://imgur.com/online.png'" onerror="this.onload=null; this.src='http://imgur.com/offline.png'" />
```

You need to have the `this.onload=null;` or when the offline image loads it will be changed to the online image because it loaded.

That's how you do it. Testing for the favicon, or a sites image, then replacing it when it loads or fails. You also disable the loading function when it errors so the offline image does not trigger the online image when it loads.